# SVG rotate deletes Elements

Tags: svg, rotation

I'm trying to generate svg-Code in a web-application.
Here's an example output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
   width="1000px" height="600px">
  <rect x="147.50198255352893" y="109.43695479777953" width="15.860428231562253" height="295.79698651863595" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="3" transform="rotate(20 155.43219666931006 257.3354480570975)"/>
  <rect x="163.36241078509119" y="405.2339413164155" width="379.85725614591587" height="-23.79064234734335" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="3" transform="rotate(20 353.2910388580491 393.3386201427438)"/>
  <rect x="543.219666931007" y="381.44329896907215" width="22.204599524187188" height="-353.6875495638382" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="3" transform="rotate(20 554.3219666931006 204.59952418715304)"/>
</svg>
```

There should be three rotated Rectangles, but somehow in Chrome, Safari, and Inkscape only one of them is displayed. I did google and have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the negative heights of the second and third `<rect />`.

If you generate this code automatically make sure these values are positive. For example, using JavaScript, wrap them up in `Math.abs( height )`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it seems so obvious. Just had to edit the way I create the elements. Thank you very much!